# What slows down an asynchronous producer

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a java program with a producer who sends messages and consumer who process them.  Below is a simplified version of my code with two tests to reproduce the problem.

- *class MyActor* is a consumer thread. It just loops to read messages from concurrent queue and count them.
- *TestestMessagesToThread* is a test who sends 200M messages synchronously by posting them to MyActor queue. It works at 6M messages per second rate on my machine.
- *testMessagesToThreadAsync* is a test who sends 200M messages asynchronously. In order to do that, it creates ExecutorService with 1 thread and messages are posted asynchronously to MyActor queue from this thread. This test barely reach 100K messages per second and degrades in performance over time.

How can I make *TestestMessagesToThread* work at the rate of *TestestMessagesToThread* while using ExecutorService or at least to understand why it it is not possible.

```
public class TestSingleThread {

    public static int WARM_UP_NUMBER = 1000000;
    public static int MSG_NUMBER = 200000000;
    private static ExecutorService _executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public static class MyActor extends Thread {
        public Queue<Integer> _messageQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
        private int _counter = 0;
        private long _time = System.currentTimeMillis();;

        public void run() {
            while (true){
                Integer msg = _messageQueue.poll();
                if (msg == null)
                    continue;

                _counter++;
                if (_counter == TestSingleThread.WARM_UP_NUMBER) {
                    System.out.println("Warm-up completed. Staring Measurement. Warm up time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - _time));
                    _time = System.currentTimeMillis();

                }

                if (_counter == TestSingleThread.MSG_NUMBER + TestSingleThread.WARM_UP_NUMBER) {
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long ms = endTime - _time;
                    System.out.println("Time for " + TestSingleActor.MSG_NUMBER+ " messages. " + ms);
                    System.out.println("msg/sec - " + (int) ((double) TestSingleActor.MSG_NUMBER / ms) * 1000);
                    _time = endTime;
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Thread Run ends");
            return;
        }


        public void tell(Integer msg) {
            _messageQueue.add(msg);
        }

        public void tellAsync(Integer msg) {
            _executor.submit(() -> {
                _messageQueue.add(msg);
            });
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMessagesToThread() throws InterruptedException {
        MyActor actor = new MyActor();
        actor.start();
        IntStream.range(0, TestSingleActor.MSG_NUMBER + TestSingleActor.WARM_UP_NUMBER).sequential().forEach(record -> actor.tell(1));
        System.out.println("Complete Sending");
        actor.join();
        return;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMessagesToThreadAsync() throws InterruptedException {
        MyActor actor = new MyActor();
        actor.start();
        IntStream.range(0, TestSingleActor.MSG_NUMBER + TestSingleActor.WARM_UP_NUMBER).sequential().forEach(record -> actor.tellAsync(5));
        System.out.println("Complete Sending");
        actor.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Memory allocation/GC? (Creating an extra instance of `Runnable` every time you submit a value may not be as cheap as you think.) `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` performance degrading beyond a certain size? `SingleThreadExecutor` performance degrading beyond a certain job queue size? These are just guesses of course.

Comment: you machine has 2 cpu cores, right?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Oh yeah, that's a cracking point too, as `MyActor` never yields.

Comment: This whole test doesn't make much sence. In the first case you push messages to the queue, that's ok. In the second case you build Runnable for each increment. Each task is sent to the internal queue of ThreadPoolExector. So you create an artificial thread which works as a transmitter between you main thread and consumer. Not to say ThreadPoolExecutor is not suitable for millions of tasks per second. You also messing with sync/async meaning. You first test sends messages to the consumer via the queue, so it's already asynchorous.

Comment: @biziclop - 'Runnable' it is. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker - yes, I have 2 cores. Why does it matters?

Comment: @AndreyCheboksarov - my goal is to make the main thread asynchronous, not the MyActor thread. Why is ThreadPoolExector not suitable for the task? Indeed, I tried fork-join pool and it works significantly faster, while it seems to me that all the "scheduling" it does should slow him down. Thanks

Comment: because in async test you have at least three threads - main thread produces items, actor thread consuming items and executor thread that does communication. with 2 cores at every moment one of a three threads will be idle.